# Can I shortcut the Begin/End async pattern by using an event to create my AsyncResult?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, events, asynchronous

I would like to easily create asynchronous methods for my WCF service. I know the way to do this is to use the Begin/End async pattern, and labeling my Begin method with AsyncPattern=true. I'm wondering if I really need to make my own AsyncResult object to handle (which I'm a bit nervous about doing) or if I can use an event handler and essentially wrap my Begin/End around the event handler's Begin/End invoke. This seems like a round-about way of doing this, but since (as far as I know) I can't subscribe or invoke the event directly from WCF it seems like a plausible solution.

```
private event EventHandler<RequestEventArgs> OnSendRequest;

[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]  // Borrowed from the interface for this example
public IAsyncResult BeginSendRequest(Request request, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    EventHandler<RequestEventArgs> handler = OnSendRequest;
    if (handler != null)
        return handler.BeginInvoke(this, new RequestEventArgs(request), callback, handler);
    return null;
}

public void EndSendRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    EventHandler<RequestEventArgs> handler = (EventHandler<RequestEventArgs>)result.AsyncState;
    handler.EndInvoke(result);
}
```

Then, obviously, something subscribes to the event to do the work. I'm also throwing away the object state passed in to my Begin method, in favor of passing the event handler as the state so I have access to it to call EndInvoke.

Is this a viable option? (I have limited knowledge and understanding of how the AsyncResult object and asynchronous programming in general work.)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx). This is [an implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) of the pattern that you are looking for.

Given [example](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2010/08/31/reactive-extensions-for-net-event-based-async-operations.aspx):

```
var client = new WebClient();
var searchUri = new Uri("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=4sq.com");
var uploadUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/uploads");

IObservable<Unit> query =
    from result in client.DownloadStringAsObservable(searchUri, new object())
    let transformed = TransformResult(result)
    from upload in client.UploadStringAsObservable(
        uploadUri,
        "POST",
        transformed,
        new object())
    select upload;

var subscription = query.Subscribe(
    x => {}, // Nothing to do
    exn => 
    {
        // Do something with the exception
    }, 
    () => 
    {
        // Indicate we're finished
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting but not applicable to my program as I am doing a WCF service/WCF client callback implementation, not a web service to a JavaScript endpoint.

Comment: Out of the box they support WCF connections. I posted a example of downloading from a website. I don't have a WCF example handy but the code is almost the same. Just call Subscribe on the wcf client object it will give you the (item, exception, finished) handlers. They ported it to javascript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am doing the same thing with the begin / end pattern. It looks like this:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginInsertWorkOrder(Dictionary<String, String> workOrderData, AsyncCallback callBack, Object state)
{
    Action<Dictionary<String, String>> command = new Action<Dictionary<String, String>>(InsertWorkOrder);
    return command.BeginInvoke(workOrderData, callBack, command);
}
```